# concurrent procedure call in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to understand the concurrent procedure call with different parameters' class. Assuming I have the procedure test and it is called concurrently like below:

```
ENTITY tb IS
END ENTITY tb;

ARCHITECTURE sim OF tb IS
  SIGNAL cnt  : integer RANGE 0 TO 3 := 0;
  SIGNAL str  : string(1 TO 5) := (OTHERS => ' ');
 
  PROCEDURE test (CONSTANT number  : IN integer RANGE 0 TO 3 := 0;
                  SIGNAL   num_str : OUT string(1 TO 5)) IS
  BEGIN
    REPORT "here";
    CASE number IS
      WHEN 0      => num_str <= "zero ";
      WHEN OTHERS => num_str <= "one  ";
    END CASE;
  END PROCEDURE;
  
BEGIN
  test(cnt, str);  -- CONCURRENT CALL TO PROCEDURE TEST
  PROCESS 
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0 TO 3 LOOP
      WAIT FOR 10 ns;
      cnt <= i;
    END LOOP;
    WAIT;
  END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE sim;
```

In **THE VHDL DESIGNER GUIED**

> Another point to note about concurrent procedure calls is that if there are no signals
> associated with in-mode or inout-mode parameters, the wait statement in the equivalent
> process does not have a sensitivity clause. If the procedure ever returns, the process suspends indefinitely. This may be useful if we want the procedure to be called only once at
> startup time.

As procedure test has no signals associated with in-mode or inout-mode, it supposes to be executed once and then suspends indefinitely. But with this example, the procedure is executed 4 times.

**Can someone explain to me what is happening or what I am missing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 11.4 of the 2008 LRM (IEEE Std 1076-2008):

> For any concurrent procedure call statement, there is an equivalent
> process statement [...] The equivalent process statement also has no
> sensitivity list, an empty declarative part, and a statement part that
> consists of a procedure call statement followed by a wait statement.
> The procedure call statement consists of the same procedure name and
> actual parameter part that appear in the concurrent procedure call
> statement.

> If there exists a name that denotes a signal in the actual part of any
> association element in the concurrent procedure call statement, and
> that actual is associated with a formal parameter of mode in or inout,
> then the equivalent process statement includes a final wait statement
> with a sensitivity clause that is constructed by taking the union of
> the sets constructed by applying the rule of 10.2 to each actual part
> associated with a formal parameter.

Forget about the last part, in your case things are super simple and your equivalent process is:

```
process
begin
  test(cnt, str);
  wait on cnt;
end process;
```

The `CONSTANT` class declaration of your procedure's declaration only indicates that (section 4.2.2.2):

> For parameters of class constant or variable, only the values of the
> actual or formal are transferred into or out of the subprogram call.

It somehow forces you to manipulate this value as if it was a constant and nothing else... inside the procedure's body. It forbids you, for instance, to use signal attributes (e.g. `number'EVENT`). But it doesn't say anything about the actual parameter that you will associate to this formal parameter when instantiating the procedure.

And the result is, logically, what you observe: your procedure is called 4 times in the equivalent process. Each time the value of the actual parameter, that is, the signal `cnt` is passed through the formal parameter `number`.

And your book is right:

> [...] if there are no signals associated with in-mode or inout-mode
> parameters, the wait statement in the equivalent process does not have
> a sensitivity clause.

Indeed, you have a signal (`cnt`) associated with an in-mode parameter (`number`).

Comment: I see. I understood from the book that the association is with the formal parameter class. That is why I was confused as the parameter number has a constant class, not a signal class.

Comment: Yes, and if you had declared it as of class signal you would have been forced to associate it to a signal, not a constant or a variable, plus you would have been allowed to manipulate it as an input signal inside your procedure's body (`number'EVENT`...) While with the `constant` class you can associate it with a signal, a variable or a constant, as you wish, but you cannot manipulate it as a signal.

Comment: you're not fully allowed to manipulate it as a signal (if it were a signal). it is an error to access `STABLE`, `QUIET`, `TRANSACTION`, and `DELAYED` signal attributes inside a procedure (but they can be passed in as other signal parameters). LRM 4.2.2.3

Comment: @tricky: Absolutely. Things are always a bit more tricky with the LRM.